# Select elements from a Javascript Array using one of the elements as a reference point

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm wondering if it's possible to pull a certain number of elements out of a Javascript array and insert them into a new array, while using one of the elements as a reference point?

This is what I'm trying to do, imagine I have an array like this:

```
var firstarray = [ 
475387453,
286235425,
738264536,
196792345,
834532623,
253463455,
535273456];
```

And then I have a variable that equals the number 286235425:

```
var element = 286235425;
```

I have another variable that equals the number 3:

```
var thenumber = 3;
```

What I want to do is go through the array, select the 3 elements that come after the ''var element'' number, and store them in a new array named "second array". 
So with the above example the result should be:

```
var secondarray = [ 
738264536,
196792345,
834532623];
```

I've seen some questions that talked about filtering array elements, but I haven't been able to find anything about selecting elements in the above way. Is such a thing even possible? 
I know it's possible to trim elements from the beginning and end of the array, but as the array will always be a different length whenever the function runs, this method isn't suitable for this problem.

Any help with this would be really appreciated,
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `splice` and `indexOf`

```js
var firstarray = [
  475387453,
  286235425,
  738264536,
  196792345,
  834532623,
  253463455,
  535273456
], element = 286235425,  thenumber = 3;

var secondarray = firstarray.splice(firstarray.indexOf(element)+1, thenumber);
console.log(secondarray)
```

Comment: I was about to write the same solution

Answer (score 1):

Grab the index where `element` is in the array using `indexOf`:

```
var index = firstarray.indexOf(element);
```

> [The `indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

Use `slice` to grab the elements from the array from the next index to the next index + `thenumber`

```
var secondarray = firstarray.slice(index + 1, index + 1 + thenumber);
```

> [The `slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/z6qd8x70/1/)